# How does updating work with Ebean and Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm new to play framework, Ebean, and ORMs in general and I have a question regarding updating fields of a persisted object.

I know that in hibernate when you call the set method of an object, it will automatically call the update method to update in the db. Does Ebean work similarly? With play framework, from what i've read, the getters and setters are generated automatically when the fields are made public. Say I have the following class in my play project:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Model{
   public String bar;
}
public static void main(String a[]){
  Foo f =  new Foo();
  f.bar = "foobar";
}
```

My question has 2 parts:

1) does the assignment f.bar="foobar"; recompile into calling f.setBar("foobar"); within play?

2) And if so, will this assignment automatically call the model's upadte method or do i need to explicitly make update methods for updating each field?

Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, play creates setter and getters automatically unless you define your custom setters or getters.
2. In order to persist your data, you have to call model.save() or model.update(), assignments does not automatically update the database.

By the way, I advice you to always write setter and getter for @ID fields, because sometimes it causes very strange errors.

Comment: Hi Omer, thanks for the response. So just as a followup question, if i want fields to be able to be updated, then it would be best to manually define my setter method and call update within it? Also if my @ID field is auto incriminating, then there is no need to have a setter for it correct?

Comment: Yep, you can write your own setter and getter for auto update but I didn't really understand why you are trying to do such a thing? Just call model.save() after whatever you change, otherwise you may query database more than it is needed. And for @ID fields, doesn't matter if is auto increment or not, just define setter and getter, as I said it causes some strange errors.